# Generating a large vector with filenames that have the same prefix in R?

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a large vector in R that contains a bunch of CSV files. I know that it's possible to do something like this:

```
files <- c('file001.csv', 'file002.csv', 'file003.csv', 'file004.csv')
```

My current issue now is how to create a vector that has 100 files (file001-file100). I know I can just concatenate it but I'm sure there has to be a way that would make it easier. I was thinking about using the `rep()` function, but am unsure how to utilize it within `c()`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `sprintf`:

```
files <- sprintf("file%03d.csv", 1:100)
head(files)
# [1] "file001.csv" "file002.csv" "file003.csv" "file004.csv" "file005.csv" "file006.csv"
tail(files)
# [1] "file095.csv" "file096.csv" "file097.csv" "file098.csv" "file099.csv" "file100.csv"
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way that is often good enough:

```
paste0("file", 1:100, ".csv")
```

Note it produces "file1.csv", "file22.csv" etc.  To get exactly what you want you can use formatC:

```
paste0("file", formatC(1:100, width=3, flag="0"), ".csv")
```